# I am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based while doing bulk update

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

i am trying to pass List as Parameter in below query then calling Hibernate Bulk update,on calling that i am getting below exception,please let me know how to set list as param value in criteria.
query is given below----
        insert into Archive(cust_id, orderNum, country, extractionType, errorCode, extractionDate)" +
                                " select cust_id, orderNum, country, extractionType, errorCode, extractionDate from OrderTest where cust_id = :ids

and my java code is

```
  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<OrderTest> customerIdList = getPurgeCriteria(session);
    if (null != customerIdList) {
      StringBuffer cust_ids = new StringBuffer();

      String purgeStatement = "insert into OrderArchive(cust_id, orderNum, country, extractionType, errorCode, extractionDate)"
          + " select * from OrderTest where cust_id in (:ids)";
      // Criteria purgeCriteria =
      // Criteria.createCriteria(OrderTest.class,purgeStatement);
      Query purgeQuery = session.createQuery(purgeStatement);
      // purgeQuery.setParameterList("ids", customerIdList);
      /*
       * for(String cust_id : customerIdList) {
       * cust_ids.append(cust_id).append(","); purgeCriteria.setParameter("ids",
       * cust_ids.toString()); System.out.println(cust_id); }
       */
      // purgeCriteria.setParameter("ids", customerIdList);
      // purgeCriteria.setParameter("ids", customerIdList);
      String deleteStatement = "delete from OrderTest where cust_id in (:delIds)";
      // Criteria deleteCriteria =
      // Criteria.createCriteria(OrderTest.class,deleteStatement);
      // deleteCriteria.setParameter("delIds", customerIdList);
      Query deleteQuery = session.createQuery(deleteStatement);
      deleteQuery.setParameterList("delIds", customerIdList);
      try {
        int res = purgeQuery.executeUpdate();
        // int res = purgePersistenceManager.update(purgeCriteria);
        logger.info("No of records inserted into archive table :" + res);
        if (res > 0) {
          int rows = deleteQuery.executeUpdate();
          // int rows = purgePersistenceManager.update(deleteCriteria);
          logger.info("No of records deleted from order test table :" + rows);
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters
>   are 1-based!
>                     at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:55)
>                     at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:61)
>                     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:382)
>                     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:362)
>                     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$39.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1147)
>                     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$39.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1141)
>                     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
>                     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
>                     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.bulkUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:1141)
>                     at in.gov.uidai.platform.impl.persistence.handler.HibernateHandler.update(HibernateHandler.java:312)
>                     at in.gov.uidai.platform.impl.persistence.provider.AbstractPersistenceProvider.update(AbstractPersistenceProvider.java:110)
>                     at in.gov.uidai.platform.impl.persistence.PersistenceDelegate.update(PersistenceDelegate.java:152)
>                     at in.gov.uidai.platform.impl.persistence.PersistenceDelegate$$FastClassByCGLIB$$9f7b2e03.invoke()
>                     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>                     at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
>                     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>                     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
>                     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>                     at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
>                     at in.gov.uidai.platform.impl.persistence.PersistenceDelegate$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e4e1748.update()
>                     at in.gov.uidai.platform.impl.persistence.PersistenceManagerProvider.update(PersistenceManagerProvider.java:320)
>                     at in.gov.uidai.platform.impl.persistence.PersistenceManagerProvider.update(PersistenceManagerProvider.java:277)
>                     at batch.impl.tasklets.PurgeProcessor.execute(PurgeProcessor.java:88)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
>                     at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:128)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:162)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:141)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
>                     at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
>                     at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
>                     at batch.impl.jobs.BatchJob.execute(BatchJob.java:48)
>                     at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
>                     at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549

Comment: Try printing the index and values to check at what point the code is failing.

Comment: Dishi as you can see i am getting a List of ids and then i am setting that in criteria as parameter using named parameter......that Criteria class in implemented in my project which is internally calling HibernateTemplate's Update method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this query alone because a think this query give multirow:

```
 " select * from OrderTest where cust_id in (:ids)";
```

For that it's give the error

Comment: @JavaStack what it does give to you?

Comment: i am getting same exception

Comment: @JavaStack I mean The quey above how many row gives to you:  " select * from OrderTest where cust_id in (:ids)"

Comment: it is returning multiple rows

Comment: @JavaStack I think this is the problem you should have just **one row**

Answer (score 0):

First Execute the purgeStatement then apply select Query. 
If you want to update the data then use save or update and use where clause in that

String purgeStatement = "insert into OrderArchive(cust_id, orderNum, country, extractionType, errorCode, extractionDate)";

String selectStatement ="select * from OrderArchive where cust_id in (:ids)" ;